# Не показывает результаты функции в C++

Tags: c++, массивы, функции

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;
double fill_array(double arr[], int size);
void show_array(const double arr2[], int size2);
double reverse_array(double arr3[], int size3);

int main()
{
    double arrm[10];
    arrm[10] = fill_array(arrm, 10);
    show_array(arrm, 10);
    reverse_array(arrm, 10);
    return 0;
}
double fill_array(double arr[], int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter: ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    return arr[10];
}
void show_array(const double arr2[], int size2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++)
    {
        cout << arr2[i] << endl;
    }
}
double reverse_array(double arr3[], int size3)
{
    int temp;
    for(int i = 0, j = 9; i < size3, j < size3 ; i++, j--)
    {
        temp = arr3[i];
        arr3[i] = arr3[j];
        arr3[j] = temp;
    }
    cout << arr3[10] << endl;
    return arr3[10];
}
```

Здравствуйте, я написал этот код чтобы она все делал через функции, в функции fillarray она заполняет массив потом этот массив переходит в функции showarray для показа массива, потом этот массив опять передается другому функцию reversearr для того что бы это функция переместила значения в массиве то есть обратная расстановка значений в массиве, и вот проблема в этой функции reversearr и она не показывает результаты, буду очень рад вашей помощи, если будут тупые ошибки то извините я новичок

Comment: не возвращайте `arrm[10]` и не присваивайте в `arrm[10]` ничего. Это выход за пределы массива что приводит к нарушению содержимого памяти.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из вашего кода массив состоит из 10 элементов, в конце функции `reverse_array` вы сначала выводите, а затем возвращаете **11** по счёту *(то есть вы смотрите за границы массива)* элемент массива, т.к. в `C++`, да и в большинстве современных языков первый индекс массива равен **0**.

Также у вас неправильно стоит условие в цикле, во первых, он должен быть 2 раза меньше длины, иначе вы поменяете все обратно, и `j` там совершенно ни к чему.

Если вам нужно выводить в данной функции только последний элемент, то правильно будет вот так.

```
double reverse_array(double arr3[], int size3)
{
    double temp;
    for(int i = 0, j = 9; i < size3 / 2; i++, j--)
    {
        temp = arr3[i];
        arr3[i] = arr3[j];
        arr3[j] = temp;
    }
    cout << arr3[size3 - 1] << endl; //либо просто 9
    return arr3[size3 - 1];
}
```

---

**P.S.** У вас в вопросе неправильно стоит тэг `css`, он не имеет никакого отношения к данному вопросу. Это каскадные таблицы стилей, предназначенные для стилизации элементов интерфейса.

Comment: `int temp;` -> `double temp;`

Comment: @AlexGlebe Спасибо, исправил